# Why does adding a border with corner radius to my button style wipe out the visualstate?

Tags: button, uwp, cornerradius, visualstates

When I add a border with corner radius to my style, it makes the VisualState PointerOver and VisualState Pressed stop working.

I tried inserting the border in several places where the IDE would allow it, but each time I got the same result: no pointer over or pressed effects.  I have another style that is identical without the border/corner radius and it works.

```
<Style x:Key="TechMenuBtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTextColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="8">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTextColor}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTextColor}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledColorBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTextColor}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are no error messages and the IDE passes the XAML, it just disables the VisualStates.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in adding a border for the purpose of corner radius, I overlooked the ContentPresenter in the Template, which holds a place to alter the CornerRadius.  Now that line looks like this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                      BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                      CornerRadius="8" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
```

This makes my VisualStates function normally.  I hope this helps someone else who has this problem.